# Is it possible to add more attributes to segement in a Doughnut chart of Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

When initializing a doughnut chart (or any other chart for that matter), is it possible to add more attributes to each segment? Currently, we are setting values for four attributes - value, color, highlight and label. I want to add couple of more attributes while initializing the chart data so that I will be able to retrieve those attributes when clicking on the chart and calling the getSegmentsAtEvent(e) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to your data

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red",
        extra: 1
    },
    ...
```

and once the chart is created, add it to the chart elements

```
...
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);

myChart.segments.forEach(function(segment, i){
   segment.extra = data[i].extra
})
```

and the access it using the element

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
    var activeSegment = myChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
    alert(activeSegment[0].extra)
};
```

---

Just click on a sector to see it in action here

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aswfsyxw/

Comment: thank you very much. I missed the second step of the process - setting the new attribute value once chart is initialized. That's why I was getting "undefined" value when accessing the attribute as in step 3.